# timepicker disableTimeRanges

Tags: jquery, date, timepicker

I have a timepicker that works just fine except when I am trying to disableTimeRanges. I have some code that assembles this string:

```
var disableTimeRanges = '[';
var count = jsonObject.length;
var i = 0;
$.each(jsonObject, function (i, obj) {
  disableTimeRanges += "['" + obj.appointmentStart.split(" ").slice(1, 3).join('') + "','" + obj.appointmentEnd.split(" ").slice(1, 3).join('') + "']";
  i++;
  if (i < count)
      disableTimeRanges += ',';
});// end $.each
disableTimeRanges += ']';
```

at this point, 
 disableTimeRanges = [['11:30:00AM','12:00:00PM'],['12:30:00PM','1:30:00PM']]

Then,

```
$('#appointmentTimeTextbox').timepicker('option', {
    'disableTimeRanges': disableTimeRanges
 });
```

I know I am doing something wrong because the chrome debugger is giving me:

Uncaught TypeError: b.disableTimeRanges.sort is not a function

Is there a problem with the array? Is there a better way to assemble the array?

Edit: fixed as an array:

```
var disableTimeRanges = new Array();
var appointmentTime = [obj.appointmentStart.split(" ").slice(1, 3).join(''), 
obj.appointmentEnd.split(" ").slice(1, 3).join('')];
disableTimeRanges.push(appointmentTime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disableTimeRanges` is not an array in your code snippet, it's a string.
Something like this should do:

```
var disableTimeRanges = [];
var count = jsonObject.length;

$.each(jsonObject, function (i, obj) {
   inRange = []
  inRange.push(obj.appointmentStart.split(" ").slice(1, 3).join(''));
  inRange.push(obj.appointmentEnd.split(" ").slice(1, 3).join(''));
  disableTimeRanges.push(inRange);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a problem with the array?

Yes, its not an array.  It's a string.  While an array prints out *as* `['A', 'B', 'C']` it is not *the same as* the string `"['A','B','C']"`

If you want to construct an array, construct an array.

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: Yeah...I appreciate that. I got it now